# My SASS files won't compile in Sublime Text 2

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass, package

I normally am able to include a config.rb file in my SASS folder and compile it right from Sublime text 2 using buildonsave package.  However, when my SASS file includes a variable like this:

```
$breakpoints: (
  break-0: 0,     // 0px      
  break-1: 640,   // 640px   
);
```

It won't compile on save.  Removing those lines and it works fine.

It gets really weird because it does work when I run sass --watch through the terminal.
Has anyone experienced this before and can offer any help?

$sass -v
$Sass 3.4.0 (Selective Steve)

Comment: Are you using Compass?  If so, which version?

Comment: Compass 1.0.1 (Polaris)